# Why only half of the stack canary is cleared?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I disassembled a simple C program (compiled by gcc) and the instructions responsible for placing the stack canary are the following:

```
mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
xor    %eax,%eax
```

Note that the canary is eight bytes (`rax`), yet, only four bytes (`xor eax eax`) get cleared.

Is this intentional? It looks like the code just leaked a half of the stack canary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With amd64, when you modify the lower 32 bits of a register, the upper 32 bits are cleared. This is different from when you modify any lower part of a register: for instance, `xor al, al` only clears the 8 low bits of `rax`.

Since `xor eax, eax` is one byte shorter than `xor rax, rax`, compilers will usually prefer the first one.

Comment: It turned out to be an embarrassingly simple question. Thanks!